# Latex help to draw bifurcation diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I am just beginning to use Latex, and I wanted to program the following bifurcation diagram from my textbook into a paper I was writing.
[image]

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \draw[] (-1, -3) -- (-1, 3) node[above] {};
        \draw[] (-2, -0.5) -- (5, -0.5) node[right] {C};
        \draw[] (0, -3) -- (0, 3) node[above] {};
        \draw[] (1, -3) -- (1, 3) node[above] {};
        \draw[] (2, -3) -- (2, 3) node[above] {P};
        \draw[] (3, 3) -- (3, -3) node[below] {$ C=\frac{kN}{4} $};
        \draw[] (4, -3) -- (4, 3) node[above] {};

        \draw[scale=0.5, domain=-3:3, smooth, variable=\y,cyan,thick]  plot ({(-\y*\y)+4}, {\y});
        
        %plotmarks
        \node[cyan] at (-1,0) {\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}};
        \node[cyan] at (0,0) {\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}};
        \node[cyan] at (1,0) {\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}};
        \node[cyan,rotate=60] at (3,0) {\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}};
        \node[cyan,rotate=60]at (4,0) {\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}};
        
        \node[cyan,rotate=60] at (-1,1.6) {\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}};
        \node[cyan,rotate=60] at (0,1.4) {\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}};
        \node[cyan,rotate=60] at (1,1.1) {\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}};
        \node[cyan,rotate=60] at (2,0.7) {\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}};
        
        \node[cyan] at (-1,-1.6) {\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}};
        \node[cyan] at (0,-1.4) {\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}};
        \node[cyan] at (1,-1.1) {\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}};
        \node[cyan] at (2,-0.7) {\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}};   
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so so much!